# We need to clamp down on these fast

Tags: discussion, notifications

https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/34934/the-best-way-to-get-stone-that-are-free-in-battle-of-kin

& its ilk have been seen a lot across all SE sites.

It seems like someone is testing out spam filters to see which manage to get through.

We ought to be closing them as soon as spotted.

Answer (score 5):

We do. Key to this process is having the community flag as spam, as mods may not see it straight away. This also helps teach the spam filters - so it is the most valuable thing you can do to cut down spam.

Additionally - if you do spot it as a cross-site spammer, pop a comment to let us know, or ping us in the chatroom and we can then escalate to the devs - who can do a network-wide block/ban.